# Using MetaData with database first in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0, ef-database-first

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. This application is developed around the existing database, so models are auto-generated using `scaffold-dbcontext`.

I am using Swagger for the documentation and I am trying to hide the navigation fields from schema, using a `SchemaFilter` developed custom annotation to hide these navigation fields from schema. Since models are auto generated, I am using MetaData to add annotation to partial class however this `MetaData` neither `ModelMetaData` works. No issue with namespaces.

Auto-generated partial model `Participant`:

```
public partial class Participant
{
    public virtual StudyParticipant? StudyParticipant { get; set; }
}

[ModelMetadataType(typeof(IParticipantMD))]
public partial class Participant
{
}

public class IParticipantMD
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual StudyParticipant? StudyParticipant { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with your shared code, I have got below output in swagger.

[image]

> I am trying to hide the navigation fields from schema, using a
> SchemaFilter developed custom annotation to hide these navigation
> fields from schema

`ModelMetadataType` is a MVC specific type that only affects **model binding** and **validation**. Therefore, it seems you are trying to hide `StudyParticipant` from your swagger schema. If that is the scenario, you could use, `[JsonIgnore]` to hide any property either from `parent class property` or `navigation property`.

**Hide Navigation Property using [JsonIgnore]:**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ParticipantController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateParticipant(Participant participant)
        {

            return new JsonResult("Somethign Went wrong") { StatusCode = 500 };
        }
    }
    public partial class Participant
    {
        public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
        public string ParticipantName { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual StudyParticipant? StudyParticipant { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudyParticipant
    {
        public int StudyParticipantId { get; set; }
        public string StudyParticipantName { get; set; }
    }


    public class IParticipantMD
    {

        public virtual StudyParticipant? StudyParticipant { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey @md-farid-uddin-kiron Thanks for the reply. The problem is the partial class "Participant" is auto generated using scaffolding so adding annotation to this file won't be possible since with evert scaffold the file will be regenerated. I have a way to hide Navigation keys using custom filter just need a way to add annotation to extended partial class so scaffold won't effect it.

Comment: If it generates autometically and if we wouldn't know it will hard to use any custom filter or anything to ommit it.